# how to define object of class A in class B to make it avaialible to all methods of class B

Tags: php, oop

I have classes are B and A. I want to define global object of B in class A, so that it is available to all methods in A

```
 class B{
    //implentation of class B
    }

    class A{

    // define object of b
    public function check(){
      //use b object here

    }

    public function check_2(){
      //use b object here
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you may `B` a parent class of `A`?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a private member of type B in A.

```
class A
{
   private $b;

   function __construct()
   {
        $this->b = new B();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Bilal Instead of just thanking him if you used his suggestion, accept it as an answer and make everyone happy.

Comment: Click the big tick above left near the top of the answer.